# What is the difference between "boasting" and "bragging" and how do you use them in everyday conversation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

In our everyday conversation how we can use these two words "boast" and "brag" and which one of them is taken in a negative sense?.Need some examples to differentiate between these two.

Comment: They are synonyms, but 'boast' is used more for the future and 'brag' for the past.  "He boasted that he would be rich"; "He bragged that he was rich".  There are some idiomatic preferences: "boast of", "brag about":  "He boasted of his abilities"; "He bragged about his abilities".

Comment: @amI examples are very clear to understand the difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really can't see a difference between the two, other than how they sound, and how they relate to various other words:

> boast (n) | boast (v) | boastful (adj)
>
> brag (n) | brag (v) | braggart (someone who excessively brags) | braggadocio (excessively boastful behavior, often considered to be mere artifice)

Even [the dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brag) uses one to define the other, so I would consider them more or less perfect synonyms.

Note: @aml suggests that "boast" is used more often for future accomplishments, and "brag" for past accomplishments, but I don't agree.  I can't think of of a single context where one couldn't be swapped for the other:

> He **boasted/bragged** of his wealth
>
> He **boasted/bragged** that he would be rich someday.